# Generate multiple pdf based on result of sql

Tags: c#, itext

I am generating a pdf with the results of sql query. There may be a possibility that sql returns more than 1 booking_id. What it does now is, it puts the result of all the booking id into one pdf. I want to fetch every booking id and generate its pdf. Basically, 1 pdf per booking_id and zip each pdf(its a requirement). Not sure if iTextSharp can help here.

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace ConvertPdf
{
class Program
{

     private static DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbConn"];
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            sda.Dispose();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //Get the data from database into datatable
        string strQuery = "select * from emp_booking where emp_booking_id in (select e.emp_booking_id from emp_booking e, emp_booking_file ef where ef.booking_date>=getdate() and e.emp_booking_id = ef.emp_booking_id)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);
        Transpose(dt);
        int i=1;

        foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
        Document document = new Document();

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("M://Bookingsheet/Pdf/Bookingsheet" + i + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));

        document.Open();
        iTextSharp.text.Font font5 = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 5);

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dt.Columns.Count);


        PdfPRow row = null;
        float[] widths = new float[] { 4f, 4f, 4f, 4f, 4f };

        table.SetWidths(widths);

        table.WidthPercentage = 100;
        int iCol = 0;
        string colname = "";
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("EmpSheet"));

        cell.Colspan = dt.Columns.Count;

       foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
        {

            table.AddCell(new Phrase(c.ColumnName, font5));
        }


            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[0].ToString(), font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[1].ToString(), font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[2].ToString(), font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[3].ToString(), font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[4].ToString(), font5));
            }

        document.Add(table);
        document.Close();
        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(@"D://BookingSheet/Pdf", @"M://BookingSheetUpload/Zip/Bookingsheet.zip");
        i++;
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: What do the results of your query look like? Is each booking ID a separate row in the query return?

Comment: @mdsimps99 Yes, each booking_id is a separate row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am not familiar with the schema of your database or the desired format of your PDF, I believe refactoring your `Main` method as below would result in a discrete PDF for each booking_id.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strQuery = "select * from emp_booking where emp_booking_id in (select e.emp_booking_id from emp_booking e, emp_booking_file ef where ef.booking_date>=getdate() and e.emp_booking_id = ef.emp_booking_id)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);
        Transpose(dt);

        foreach (DataRow r in dt)
        {
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("<Unique filename for each booking ID>", FileMode.Create));
            document.Open();
            iTextSharp.text.Font font5 = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 5);

            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dt.Columns.Count);
            float[] widths = new float[] { 4f, 4f, 4f, 4f, 4f };
            table.SetWidths(widths);
            table.WidthPercentage = 100;

            foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
            {
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(c.ColumnName, font5));
            }

            table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[0].ToString(), font5));
            table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[1].ToString(), font5));
            table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[2].ToString(), font5));
            table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[3].ToString(), font5));
            table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[4].ToString(), font5));

            document.Add(table);
            document.Close();
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(@"<parent directory of pdf>", @"M://BookingSheetUpload/Zip/<unique zip name>.zip");
        }
    }
```

This will iterate over each `DataRow` returned by your query and generate a PDF per row. Note that each PDF and .zip file should be assigned a unique name.

I also might suggest moving some of this code out in to other classes or at least static methods of class Program. Again, I am not familiar with your application, but it seems like the `Main` method is doing a lot of the heavy lifting here.

Comment: I get this error in foreach statement : 
Error CS1579 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'DataTable' because 'DataTable' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: Change `foreach(DataRow r in dt)` to `foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows)`

Comment: so I updated my code(edited above) and it generates the pdf for the first booking ID and then exits.It just generates BookingSheet1.pdf.

Comment: You’re setting i = 1 in the loop each time, so the i++ statement effectively does nothing. Initialize i outside of the for loop, otherwise it’s just gonna overwrite the same file every time.